# Is sharing cache/persisted dataframes between databricks notebook possible?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, databricks

I want to cache a table(dataframe) in one notebook and use it in another notebook , I am using same databricks cluster for both the notebooks.

Please suggest if this is possible , If yes then how ?

Comment: add information on what language is used, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can share dataframe between notebooks.

On the first notebook please register it as temp view:

```
df_shared.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("df_shared")
```

On the second notebook please read it from global temp database:

```
global_temp_db = spark.conf.get("spark.sql.globalTempDatabase")
df_shared= table(global_temp_db + ".df_shared")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible based on the following setups .

You can register your dataframe as `temp` table . The lifetime of temp view created by `createOrReplaceTempView()` is tied to Spark Session in which the dataframe has been created.

```
spark.databricks.session.share to true
```

this setup global temporary views to share temporary views across notebooks.
ref : [link](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#spark-session-isolation)